# Time elapsed since AC supply unplugged

Tags: android

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the elapsed time since the phone was unplugged from AC supply. I know that I can register a receiver to catch battery events - but this just works if my service is running already when the status changes.

In my case I assume that the application is started when the AC supply was already plugged out before and I then want to retrieve the time

thanks in advance,
cheers

Martin

Comment: I think you need to read up on broadcast receivers. Catch battery actions, start your service, store times

Comment: I do all these things in already, but I'd be interested in the particular case that the service gets information from a time before it was started.
Something like the output of the "uptime" command but for the battery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looks like there's no way to figure out

Comment: Of course it's possible. 
What's wrong with using broadcast receivers? Your app does *not* need to be running before receiving a broadcast. Also, the pre-installed Battery Usage app shows this value, so have a look at its source code.

Comment: I did, but it uses functionality which is not provided by the API

http://tinyurl.com/BatteryInfo-java

Answer (score 1):

JuicePlotter does this somehow (http://latedroid.com/juiceplotter), it graphs battery events from before the app was started, or even installed. I don't know how it works, but it would be a good place to do some research.

Comment: I think it just does this when the service was already running in the background - if the app is started initially it also doesn't seem to have the information. But a nice app, by the way :)